# How do I use l3skip as an argument to setlength?

Tags: expl3, latex3, vskip

How do I recover send l3skip expressions to `setlength`?
Or: How do I convert `length + stretch - shrink` to `length plus stretch minus shrink\relax`?

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_const:Nn \c__par_skip    { 1ex  +0.2ex     -0.1ex   }
\setlength {\c__par_skip}   % NOPE!
\exp_args:Nv \setlength {\skip_use:N \c__par_skip}   % ALSO NO: skip_use:N evaluates
```

Comment: Your `\setlength` misses a mandatory argument. Also, note that in a `\skip_const:Nn` your `1ex + 0.2ex -0.1ex` (which is evaluated to `1.1ex` and converted to `pt`) is not the same as `1ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex`. `l3skip` doesn't change the syntax for skips.

Comment: Also note that variables (and constants) should include the package name/abbreviation. So instead of `\c__par_skip` you should use `\c__mypkg_par_skip`. And if you correctly input the skip as `\skip_const:Nn \c__mypkg_par_skip { 1ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex }` then you can use `\skip_use:N`, e.g., `\newlength\mylength\setlength\mylength{\skip_use:N \c__mypkg_par_skip}`.

Comment: No, you cannot. `+` and `-` have special meaning in parsing a glue expression; they mean arithmetic operations. `plus` and `minus` are keywords that specify stretch and shrink components of a glue, respectively. You cannot mix these two kinds of “keywords”. For example, this is legal: `\skip_const:Nn \c__par_skip { 1ex plus 0.1ex+0.1ex minus 0.1ex - 0.1ex plus 0.1ex minus -0.05ex }`. Also, you misunderstood the syntax of `\setlength`: Its LaTeX3 equivalent would be `\skip_set:Nn`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer:

Your input syntax for `\skip_const:Nn` is most likely not what you want. The skips in the expression are evaluated, so you can use simple calculations, and your `1ex + 0.2ex - 0.1ex` is evaluated as such a calculation, and the result is `1.1ex` (which is turned into `pt`/`sp` by TeX, `l3skip` uses the underlying registers of TeX).

Instead if you want to input a skip with glue you should still input `plus` and `minus` like so:

```tex
\skip_const:Nn \c__douglas_par_skip { 1ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex }
```

With `article` loaded and the default font size this will result in the `\c__douglas_par_skip` being set to `4.30554pt plus 0.86108pt minus 0.43057pt`.

Now if you want to assign this to a LaTeX2e length you can simply use `\skip_use:N` which will result in the above string being inserted. So the following does what you want:

```tex
\newlength \douglaslength
\setlength \douglaslength { \skip_use:N \c__douglas_par_skip }
```

Complete MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_const:Nn \c__douglas_par_skip {1ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}
\newlength \douglaslength
\setlength \douglaslength { \skip_use:N \c__douglas_par_skip }
\showthe \douglaslength
\stop
```

prints

```
> 4.30554pt plus 0.86108pt minus 0.43057pt.
l.7 \showthe \douglaslength
```

to the terminal.

Comment: How did you get `4.30554pt plus 142.26378pt minus 85.35826pt`?!

Comment: @RuixiZhang was a relict of me playing around (5cm and 3cm, I think). Edited out, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A skip is an *ordered triple of values*, conventionally input as

```
<length1> plus <length2> minus <length2>
```

The first length is specified with one of the standard units (`pt`, `mm`, `cm` and so on); the other two can be specified with a standard unit or with

```
fil    fill    filll
```

corresponding to “order of infinite glue”. When summing skips, the addition is componentwise, where infinite glues win over finite ones and the one with more `l`'s wins over those with less `l`'s. If either `plus` or `minus` is missing (or both), the assigned value in the triple is implicitly `0pt`. The lengths must be specified in the precise order.

The keywords `plus` and `minus` just resemble the standard names for addition and subtraction, but in no way they denote addition or subtraction.

So it's wrong to input a skip as you think: `1ex +0.2ex -0.1ex` would be out of place in a skip specification with the primitive assignment

```
\skip0=1ex +0.2ex -0.1ex
```

because as soon as TeX doesn't see `plus` following `<length1>` it stops the assignment.

With the `expl3` assignment

```
\skip_const:Nn \c__par_skip { 1ex +0.2ex -0.1ex}
```

a different approach is used, because `expl3` assignments allow “expressions”. But skips must anyway be input in the standard conventional way. With that expression you simply get the equivalent of

```
\skip0=1.1ex
```

How do “skip expressions” work? Suppose you have

```
\skip_new:N \l_dmt_a_skip
\skip_new:N \l_dmt_b_skip
\skip_new:N \l_dmt_c_skip

\skip_set:Nn \l_dmt_a_skip { 12pt plus 6pt minus 3pt }
\skip_set:Nn \l_dmt_b_skip { 24pt plus 1fil }
\skip_set:Nn \l_dmt_c_skip { \l_dmt_a_skip + \l_dmt_b_skip }

\skip_show:N \l_dmt_c_skip
```

then you get

```
\l_dmt_c_skip=36.0pt plus 1.0fil minus 3.0pt
```

because of how componentwise addition works *and* by the rules on infinite glue.

Comment: I don’t see how `1ex +0.2ex -0.1ex` is equivalent to `0.2ex`… Did you mean `1.1ex`?

Comment: @RuixiZhang Yes, I did wrong operations. Fixing.