# How do I get the rubber components of an l3skip?

Tags: expl3, lengths, vskip

Related to my [question on l3skip to \setlength](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639447/how-do-i-use-l3skip-as-an-argument-to-setlength).

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_const:Nn \c__par_skip { 1ex plus 0.2ex plus 0.1ex }
\skip_gimme_the_stretch:NN \g__par_stretch_fp \c__par_skip  % 0.2ex
\skip_gimme_the_shrink:NN \g__par_shrink_fp \c__par_skip    % 0.1ex
```

I mainly want this as a way to implement multiplying a skip by a constant that preserves the rubber components.

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_const:Nn \c__a_skip { 1ex plus 0.2ex plus 0.1ex }
\glue_add:NnN \c__a_skip {2} \l__tmpa_skip
\skip_vertical:N \l__tmpa_skip  % 2ex plus 0.4ex minus 0.2ex
```

But perhaps there's already a way to do this?

Comment: What about `\skip_eval:n`? If you do `\skip_eval:n { \c__a_skip * 2 }` you get each component multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question kinda has two parts, so for the first, here's an implementation of `\turnbull_skip_stretch:N` and `\turnbull_skip_shrink:N` that return the stretch and shrink components of a skip, respectively.  They are expandable, so you can use them like:

```latex
\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \turnbull_skip_stretch:N \c_turnbull_par_skip }
```

to store the stretch component of `\c_turnbull_par_skip` in `\l_tmpa_dim`, for example. Here's the code:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn

% definition
\scan_new:N \s__turnbull_stop
\cs_new:Npn \turnbull_skip_space:N #1
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__turnbull_skip_space:w \dim_use:N #1 ~
      \s__turnbull_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npx \turnbull_skip_stretch:N #1
  {
    \exp_not:n { \exp_after:wN \__turnbull_skip_stretch:w \dim_use:N } #1
      \tl_to_str:n {~minus~plus~0.0pt~minus~} \s__turnbull_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npx \turnbull_skip_shrink:N #1
  {
    \exp_not:n { \exp_after:wN \__turnbull_skip_shrink:w \dim_use:N } #1
      \tl_to_str:n {~plus~minus~0.0pt~plus~} \s__turnbull_stop
  }
\use:e
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__turnbull_skip_stretch:w
        #1 \tl_to_str:n {~plus~} #2 \tl_to_str:n {~minus~} #3 \s__turnbull_stop
      {#2}
    \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__turnbull_skip_shrink:w
        #1 \tl_to_str:n {~minus~} #2 \tl_to_str:n {~plus~} #3 \s__turnbull_stop
      {#2}
    \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__turnbull_skip_space:w
        #1 ~ #2 \s__turnbull_stop
      {#1}
  }

% example
\skip_const:Nn \c_turnbull_par_skip { 1pt plus 0.2pt minus 0.1pt }
\skip_show:N \c_turnbull_par_skip

\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \turnbull_skip_stretch:N \c_turnbull_par_skip }
\dim_show:N \l_tmpa_dim

\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \turnbull_skip_shrink:N \c_turnbull_par_skip }
\dim_show:N \l_tmpa_dim

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

For the second part, I think you are going the difficult path.  It's easy to take the definitions above and write:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \turnbull_skip_multiply:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \skip_set:Nn #1
      {
              \skip_eval:n { ( \turnbull_skip_space:N #1 ) * #2 }
        plus  \skip_eval:n { ( \turnbull_skip_stretch:N #1 ) * #2 }
        minus \skip_eval:n { ( \turnbull_skip_shrink:N #1 ) * #2 }
      }
  }

\skip_const:Nn \c_turnbull_par_skip { 1pt plus 0.2pt minus 0.1pt }

\skip_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_skip \c_turnbull_par_skip
\turnbull_skip_multiply:Nn \l_tmpa_skip { 2 }
\skip_show:N \l_tmpa_skip

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

but it's much easier to use the `\multiply` primitive directly (although it requires you to make a copy of `\tex_multiply:D`, which is not in best practices):

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \__turnbull_multiply:w \tex_multiply:D
\cs_new_protected:Npn \turnbull_skip_multiply:Nn #1 #2
  { \__turnbull_multiply:w #1 by \int_eval:n {#2} \scan_stop: }

\skip_const:Nn \c_turnbull_par_skip { 1pt plus 0.2pt minus 0.1pt }

\skip_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_skip \c_turnbull_par_skip
\turnbull_skip_multiply:Nn \l_tmpa_skip { 2 }
\skip_show:N \l_tmpa_skip

\ExplSyntaxOff
\stop
```